# Querying a log file with multiple XML objects

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive, xquery

I am working on a project to analyze log files in Hadoop. The files store the meta data in XML Format. The problem is, each file stores several requests, and hence there are multiple root elements in the same file. I cannot change the log files. Can someone help with how to query the file using Hive?
An example of the file is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
    <book>
       <title>C Proramming </title>
       <price> 120.00 </price>
    </book> 
    <book>
        <title> Java for Dummies </title>
        <price> 400 </price>
    </book>
```

Now, there are 2 root elements, or rather none, as you would like to see it. How do I go ahead and query such a file?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is a great example of why XML is a terrible format for logging- not only is it enormously verbose, doubling the size of log entries, but the unspecified limits of a log entry mean almost inevitably malformed documents. You can just wrap a copy of the whole thing in a root element when you need to analyse it to create a valid doc but it's a nasty hack, so I'm not going to suggest it as an answer.

Comment: @glenatron I would rather argue that your comment is a great example of people blaming XML for no good reason. First, the OP never complained about a too big log file, so fixing a problem that does not exist is quite pointless. In the real world, it often doesn't matter how big the file is (who cares whether it is 1MB or 2MB?). Of course there are cases where it does matter, but then XML might simply be not the best choice. Also, putting it into a smart XML database will get rid of the verbosity and storage will be much, much smaller

Comment: Also, how is it the fault of XML that this document is not well-formed? There are very few rules which are required to have a well-formed document. What makes XML a "terrible format", because some program is generating invalid data? In every storage format you have rules how to store stuff. It is no problem to create a single root node, hence it is in no way "inevitably"

Comment: @dirkk I don't care if it is 1-2mb, but once you get to a few hundred megabytes or a couple of gb, managing it becomes challenging and typically half the markup is bloat. I am not saying XML is a _terrible format_ I am saying it is a _terrible format for logging_ because you never know when a log is going to end so it is essentially impossible to make a log into a well-formed XML document unless you parse it every time you log anything, which makes logging a heavy task. There are loads of good log formats. XML is none of them.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a well-formed XML documument as @glenatron points out. You only have two options here if you want to process it as XML:

1) Wrap the elements in a root element to create a well-formed document

2) Break that file into many small XML documents.

I am not sure what tools you have available to you, but if I was reading it from Java, I would probably create a custom sub-classed InputStream or Reader to dynamically prefix it with a start element (after the document declaration) and postfix with an end element. In this way I could then feed this stream/reader to any XML DOM/SAX parser or XPath/XQuery engine and it would treat it as a valid XML document.